# How to use as.DNAbin{ape} with DNA sequences stored in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dna-sequence, ape-phylo

I have a dataframe with loci names in one column and DNA sequences in the other. I'm trying to use `as.DNAbin{ape}` or similar to create a DNAbin object.

Here some example data:

> x <- structure(c("55548", "43297", "35309", "34468", "AATTCAATGCTCGGGAAGCAAGGAAAGCTGGGGACCAACTTCTCTTGGAGACATGAGCTTAGTGCAGTTAGATCGGAAGAGCA", 
>     "AATTCCTAAAACACCAATCAAGTTGGTGTTGCTAATTTCAACACCAACTTGTTGATCTTCACGTTCACAACCGTCTTCACGTT", 
>     "AATTCACCACCACCACTAGCATACCATCCACCTCCATCACCACCACCGGTTAAGATCGGAAGAGCACACTCTGAACTCCAGTC", 
>     "AATTCTATTGGTCATCACAATGGTGGTCCGTGGCTCACGTGCGTTCCTTGTGCAGGTCAACAGGTCAAGTTAAGATCGGAAGA"), .Dim = c(4L, 2L))

If I try `y <- as.DNA(x)` R creates a sort of DNAbin object with 4 DNA sequences (the 4 rows  of the example) of length 2 (the two columns, I assume), there is no labels and of course the base composition doesn't work either.

The documentation is not very clear, but after playing with the woodmouse example data of the package I think that what I need to do is to create a matrix with each base as a column and then use `as.DNAbin`. I.e. in the above example a 4 x 84 matrix (1 column for locus name and 83 for the sequences?). Any advice on how to do this? Or any better idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First parameter of `as.DNAbin` should be *a matrix or a list containing the DNA sequences, or an object of class "alignment"*. So, your idea is right.

Given `x` is the structure from original post, the code below prepares matrix `y`:

```
y <- t(sapply(strsplit(x[,2],""), tolower))
rownames(y) <- x[,1]
```

Then `as.DNAbin(y)` shows:

```
4 DNA sequences in binary format stored in a matrix.

All sequences of same length: 83 

Labels: 55548 43297 35309 34468 

Base composition:
    a     c     g     t 
0.289 0.262 0.205 0.244
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works. Just small edit (so small it doesn't let me do it: in intro parragraph it should say `as.DNAbin` not `as.DNA`